# Firefox browser: $User.UITheme and $User.UIThemeDisplayed return wrong value in Lightning Experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience

While trying to overcome the problem with `<apex:outputLink target="_blank">` not working under Lightning Experience, I found [this atricle](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_multipurpose_pages); they propose checking the `{!$User.UIThemeDisplayed}` [return value](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_useruitheme.htm) to understand, if the VF page is currently rendered under Classic UI or LX (Lightning Experience) UI.

I applied `<apex:outputLink target="{!IF($User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme3', '_blank', '_self')}" ...>` as a solution, so that the link either opens in a new tab under Classic UI, or "replaces" currently viewed page under the LX UI.

This solution worked correctly just yesterday, but today the check fails: for some odd reason, **`$User.UIThemeDisplayed` now returns `"Theme3"` even when I access the page from LX UI.**
I have created a testing VF page to check this behavior, (also checking the presence of some JS objects available only under Salesforce1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(myContext){
    myContext.ForceUI = myContext['ForceUI'] || {};

    myContext.ForceUI.UserUIThemeDisplayed = '{!$User.UIThemeDisplayed}';
    myContext.ForceUI.UserUITheme = '{!$User.UITheme}';
    myContext.ForceUI.isSalesforce1 = (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && sforce && !!sforce.one;

    // Output results into the <div> element on this page
    var targetEl = document.getElementById('debugOutput');
    if (targetEl && myContext.ForceUI) {
        targetEl.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(myContext.ForceUI, null, '    ') + '</pre>';
    }
})(this);
</script>
```

DebugOutput under Classic UI:

```
{
    "UserUIThemeDisplayed": "Theme3",
    "UserUITheme": "Theme3",
    "isSalesforce1": false
}
```

DebugOutput under Lignting Experience UI:

```
{
    "UserUIThemeDisplayed": "Theme3",
    "UserUITheme": "Theme3",
    "isSalesforce1": true
}
```

As you can see, only checking the `sforce` object's availability has worked correctly...

Looks like a bug?.. Has anyone faced with the same problem?

---

Additional info: I have just found this is a browser-specific issue. This is **only reproduced under Mozilla Firefox browser**.